# Ошибка при попытке использовать переменную из .py в .kv

Tags: python, kivy

Нужно использовать переменную из питон файла в файл .kv в качестве текста для Label. При этом выдаётся ошибка

```
"File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 615, in _apply_rulerctx['ids'])
   File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 254, in create_handlercause=tb)"
```

Вот код .py

```
class WBLIconDegree(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        super(WBLIconDegree, self).__init__()

        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.size_hint = (.5, 1)
        self.degree = WBLDegree()

class WBLDegree():

    def __init__(self):
    super(WBLDegree, self).__init__()
```

А вот код .kv

```
<WBLIconDegree>
    BoxLayout:
        height: self.parent.height
        width: self.parent.width
        Image:
            x: self.parent.x
            y: self.parent.y
            source: 'data\Icons\sun-and-cloud.png'
        Label:
            x: self.parent.x
            y: self.parent.y
            font_size: 30
            text: '(%s)'%(WBLIconDegree.degree) + u'\u02DA'
```

Подскажите, как это сделать. Переменная будет типом Int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text: '(%s)'%(root.degree) + u'\u02DA'
```